# TikZ externalization not working on Windows 7

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, tikz-external

TikZ externalization is not working on Windows 7 with Tex Live 2016 and I cannot seem to find out why.

I compile with `lualatex -shell-escape main.tex`, where `main.tex` has the content

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}
                    [%
                        xmin=0,
                        xmax=100,
                        xmajorgrids,
                        ymin=0,
                        ymax=0.9,
                        ymajorgrids,
                    ]
                    \addplot [color=blue,solid,line width=2.0pt,forget plot] table[row sep=crcr]
                    {
                        5   0.885230548905366\\
                        7   0.706932087191873\\
                        9   0.58113883008419\\
                        11  0.491951469859456\\
                    };
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        \caption{CAPTION.}
        \label{LABEL}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "main-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjo
b{main}\input{main}"' ========
lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "main-fig
ure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "main-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{m
ain}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'main-figure0' (expec
ted one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system c
alls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also name
d 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error
messages can be found in 'main-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to t
ypeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.38                    \end{tikzpicture}

?
```

It does work on Overleaf:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/dtkwynbzqhsp

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need more that shell escape for it to work with lualatex. The developers have changed a lot. You probably need the shellesc package as well (you should be able to search the issue on the site)

Comment: And overleaf is probably not using tl16

Comment: @daleif What does Overleaf use then?

Comment: An older version probably (those changes in lualatex came with the '16 release and created a lot of problems for latex users). If would make sense for overleaf and similar systems to be quite conservative in their update strategy. But I don't use any of them so I do not know the details.

Comment: @daleif Introducing the command `\usepackage{shellesc}` seems to solve the problem indeed. Do you want to answer this question, or do you want me to do it? Wouldn't want to take any of your credits ;). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you had a look in the log file on a project that is created on overleaf? The engine and version is listed at the top of the log file.

Comment: Btw don't use center to center inside floats replace the begin part with `\centering` and loose the end part. And don't use the H option.

Comment: Introducing what command?

Comment: @daleif `\usepackage{shellesc}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45395/discussion-between-adriaan-and-daleif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lualatex has changed a lot in the '16 release. There are two new packages that the latex team have provided that still allows you access to stuff that was changed.

One issue is with shell escape, you will probably need the shellesc package as well as the command line option.